# Retrieve specific data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase, I tried to look into the documentation and youtube but just couldn't figure it out.
I have a simple id and display_name structure database in firebase:

```
 AppName{
  users{
   HzIYTbIbSzSlinF1Aa52WYUcD4E2{
    display_name: "Greg Nks"
   }
}
```

And I want the data to get into a User object, with Id(string) and display_name(string)
I tried to test my retrieving data, but I cant get it.
this is my code:

```
public void initializeVariables(View view){
    mToolBar = view.findViewById(R.id.users_appBar);
    usersRv = view.findViewById(R.id.friends_list_rv);
    mLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
    myDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user!=null){

            }
        }
    };

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //remember it will called in the start of the fragment
            showData(dataSnapshot); //TODO fix the reading from firebase
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    User u= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    u=null;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Class User {
    private String display_name;
    private String userKey;
    public User(){
    }

    public User(String name,String key){
    display_name = name;
    userKey = key;
    }
     public void setDisplay_name(Sring name)
    {
    display_name = name;
    }
    public String getDisplay_name()
    {
    return display_name;
    }
     public void setUserKey(Sring key)
    {
    userKey = key;
    }
    public String getUserKey()
    {
    return userKey;
    }
}
```

now change this statment

```
User u= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

by this :

```
String key = datasnapshot.getKey();
    String name = datasnapshot.child('display_name').getValue().toString();
    User user = new User(name, key);
```

Comment: this is the key not the id

Comment: sorry it's my fault i have edit the answer for the name

Comment: now the code edited use it and please tell me the result

Comment: hey, thank you very much! I have some other error so I cant run It right now, I will update later if it worked. Just for my understanding - the datashot.getValue gives me the id(all the id's in the database? spesific one?). I mean what will happen when my database will contain more than one user?

Comment: glade to help you :)

Comment: Sure, dont worry ! Thanks

Comment: It gave me this error:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: which statment?

Comment: dataSnapshot.child("display_name").getValue().toString();

Comment: @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String name= snapshot.child("display_name").getValue().toString();
                               
                            }

Comment: Where should I put this?